# Извлечь путь к иконке из манифеста .apk файла

Tags: android

Загружаем .apk файлы на сервер. После этого требуется извлечь файл иконки и положить рядом.

Пробовал разбирать .apk руками и искать иконку, чтобы понять систему по которой определяется путь по которому лежит иконка.
Систему эту понять не смог. Только то, что иконка чаще всего лежит в папке, которая в названии содержит подстроку drawable-hdpi, которая лежит в папке res. Но не обязательно. Бывает вообще нет файла с названием похожим на icon.

Распарсил манифест и нашел в нем такую запись:

```
application: {
     theme: 'resourceId:0x7f110007',
     label: 'resourceId:0x7f100020',
     icon: 'resourceId:0x7f0e0000',
     много еще чего...
}
```

Что такое 0x7f0e0000? Можно ли из этой записи определить путь до иконки?

Answer (score 1):

0x7f0e0000 - это созданное средой разработки значение переменной идентифицирующее ресурс - иконку. В генерируемом классе `R.java` можно узнать имя ресурса:

```
public static final class mipёmap {
 public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f0a0000;
 public static final int ic_launcher_round=0x7f0a0001;
}
```

Но, к сожалению, папки mipёmap нету, есть папки mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, и т.д. Надеюсь, что чем-нибудь помог.